# rpm and defattr

Tags: rpm, rspec

Why does

```
%files ram
%defattr(-,root,root,644)
%dir %attr(755, root, root) /usr/lib/ram/postd
/usr/lib/ram/postd/about
/usr/lib/ram/postd/local.conf
/usr/lib/ram/postd/local.init.conf
/usr/lib/ram/postd/param
%attr(755, root, root) /usr/lib/ram/postd/apply
%attr(755, root, root) /usr/lib/ram/postd/input
%attr(755, root, root) /usr/lib/ram/postd/query
```

create *ALL* the files with 755?

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 kostyrev kostyrev   37 Aug 25 19:42 about
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 kostyrev kostyrev  160 Aug 25 19:42 apply
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 kostyrev kostyrev  548 Aug 25 19:42 input
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 kostyrev kostyrev 1178 Aug 25 19:42 local.conf
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 kostyrev kostyrev   61 Aug 25 19:42 local.init.conf
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 kostyrev kostyrev  183 Aug 25 19:42 param
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 kostyrev kostyrev    0 Aug 25 19:42 query
```

Isn't it supposed to apply `defattr` to files with no explicit `attr` setting?

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is off.  The `%defattr` macro looks like:

```
%defattr(<file mode>, <user>, <group>, <dir mode>)
```

So:

```
%defattr(-,root,root,644)
```

Means: keep the file mode of the file as it was installed, set owner to `root`, group to `root`, and set the permission of *directories* to `644`.  You probably want:

```
%defattr(0644,root,root)
```

**Update**

Here's an example.  It's shorter than what you're using, which makes
it easier to discuss here, but I think it demonstrates how things
work.  If we start with the following files in an archive `sotest-1.0.0.tar.gz`:

```
drwxrwxr-x lars/lars         0 2015-08-30 15:51 sotest-1.0.0/
-rwxr-xr-x lars/lars        28 2015-08-30 09:36 sotest-1.0.0/script1
-rw-rw-r-- lars/lars        16 2015-08-30 09:36 sotest-1.0.0/file1
-rw-rw-r-- lars/lars        14 2015-08-30 15:51 sotest-1.0.0/file2
```

And the following spec file:

```
Name:       sotest
Version:    1.0.0
Release:    1%{?dist}
Summary:    A test for StackOverflow
BuildArch:  noarch

License:    GPL
Source0:    %{name}-%{version}.tar.gz

%description
%{summary}

%package subpackage
Summary: A test subpackage

%description subpackage
A test subpackage

%prep
%setup -q

%build

%install

install -Dp -m 755 file1 %{buildroot}%{_libdir}/%{name}/file1
install -Dp -m 755 file2 %{buildroot}%{_sysconfdir}/%{name}
install -Dp -m 755 script1 %{buildroot}%{_bindir}/%{name}


%files
%defattr(0644, root, root)
%{_sysconfdir}/%{name}

%files subpackage
%defattr(0644, root, root)
%{_bindir}/%{name}
%{_libdir}/%{name}/file1
```

I think this example is largely simple to what you're using.

When installed, everything will have mode `0644`, even though the
files were installed with mode `0755`.  This is because the
`%defattr` macro is telling rpmbuild to use these permissions for all
files that we do not provide an explicit permission.

If I add:

```
%attr(0755, root, root) %{_bindir}/%{name}
```

Then I get mode 0755 for that file as expected.  However, the *other*
way of fixing this is to modify our `%install` section to simply
install things with the correct permissions, like this:

```
install -Dp -m 644 file1 %{buildroot}%{_libdir}/%{name}/file1
install -Dp -m 644 file2 %{buildroot}%{_sysconfdir}/%{name}
install -Dp -m 755 script1 %{buildroot}%{_bindir}/%{name}
```

And then I can use this:

```
%files
%defattr(-, root, root)
%{_sysconfdir}/%{name}

%files subpackage
%defattr(-, root, root)
%{_bindir}/%{name}
%{_libdir}/%{name}/file1
```

Which tells rpm to simply use the mode on the file as it was installed
(but modify the owner and group). This makes the `%files` section much simpler, since you don't have to clutter it up with explicit `%attr` macros for individual files.

Comment: still the same perms with
`%files ram
%defattr(0644,root,root)
%dir /usr/lib/ram/postd
/usr/lib/ram/postd/about
/usr/lib/ram/postd/local.conf
/usr/lib/ram/postd/local.init.conf
/usr/lib/ram/postd/param
%attr(755, root, root) /usr/lib/ram/postd/apply
%attr(755, root, root) /usr/lib/ram/postd/input
%attr(755, root, root) /usr/lib/ram/postd/query`

Comment: Can you post your actual spec file, or a minimal version of it that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/TC5KeGnX
thanks for help!